# Filled level sets of harmonic functions

Tags: gn.general-topology, harmonic-functions

Let $f$ be an enitre function. Define the "filled level set of $f$ as follows:
$$A_M(f):=\{z\in{\mathbb C}:\ |f(z)|\le M\}$$

Theorem 1 in [Topological Properties of Level-Sets of Entire Functions](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03322086) asserts that the "filled level set" of an entire function is a K-set (or Arakelian set, that is, a closed set with connected and locally connected at $\infty$ complement in ${\mathbb C}_\infty$).

I am interesting in translate some results on complex variables to the harmonic framework. So my question is:
Does someone knows if this theorem remains true for harmonic functions in ${\mathbb R}^N$?

Comment: Maybe related to [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45773).

Comment: The complement of the filled level set of an entire function $\{ z:|f(z)|>M\}$ is not necessarily connected, example $f(z)=\cos z$, $M=2$. So what are you really asking?

Comment: Its complement in the extended complex plane ${\mathbb C}_\infty$. Sorry.

Comment: Not related, Loïc.

Comment: If $f$ is a non-constant (real-valued) harmonic function, then, my the maximum principle, each component of the set $\{f > M\}$ (or $\{f < -M\}$) is unbounded, and so $\{|f| > M\} \cup \{\infty\}$ is connected in $\mathbb R^n \cup \{\infty\}$, the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R^n$. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: At least for the complex case (N=2) this is not so. See, for instance [Uniform approximation on closed subsets of C by polyanalytic functions, Example 3](http://www.crm.cat/en/Publications/Publications/2003/Preprints/pr544.pdf) @MateuszKwaśnicki

Comment: @JoséAntonioPrado-Bassas: Right: the set is required to be *locally* connected at $\infty$, not just connected — I missed that part. Sorry!

Comment: Don’t apologize. It  is a key but not very intuitive point.